# convert image blob: to php gd

Tags: php, blob

**Good night I have a problem with this**

```
imagecreatefromstring('blob:https://myweb.com/1475db94-d450-44c7-a02f-c06e9fe46a6a');
```

**error output**

> Message: 'imagecreatefromstring(): Data is not in a recognized format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `blob` isn't any kind of protocol PHP handles (see http://php.net/manual/wrappers.php).
2. `imagecreatefromstring()` expects a string of binary data, not any kind of URI.

I think you need

```php
$uri = 'https://myweb.com/1475db94-d450-44c7-a02f-c06e9fe46a6a';
$image = imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($uri));
```